# How do i display the modified dot in the red button of an NSWindow

Tags: cocoa, nswindow

Can't find the Cocoa API call to set the modified marker of a window.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you’re using the NSDocument architecture it should happen automatically.

If not, and you’re using NSWindowController, you should use its `setDocumentEdited:` method.

If you’re not using a window controller, use NSWindow’s `setDocumentEdited:` method.

Comment: I shouldn't start coding in the morning without a coffee. Thanks.